# How to group array elements breaking every condition with pure functional programming?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming

Suppose I have an array `arr` with several elements. I want to create an array of groups of elements of `arr` (array of arrays), in which each group is composed of the next element that matched some condition `fn` and every next element in sequence until the next match.

So I want to kinda slice the array in groups starting by matching elements.
I made the following code to do it, but it's too imperative to me:

```
var sliceGroupingBy = (arr, fn) => {
  var newArray = [];
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (fn(el)) {
      newArray.push([el]);
    } else {
      newArray.slice(-1)[0].push(el);
    }
  });
  return newArray;
};
```

Example:

```
var in = [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 1];
var out = sortaGroupBy(in, x => x % 2 === 1);
// [ [ 1, 2, 4, 6 ], [ 3, 4, 6 ], [ 5 ], [ 7, 8, 8 ], [ 1 ] ]
```

I wonder what's the more functional way to do it, using the regular functional operations only (no if or aux. array).

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition

Comment: Also remember that functional programming means different things to different people. A function that is impure *internally* but doesn't mutate any of its inputs or modify global state is probably 'pure enough'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make it more functional by using `reduce` instead of some imperative looping:

```
function sliceGroupingBy(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce((newArray, el) => {
    if (fn(el))
      newArray.push([el]);
    else
      newArray[newArray.length-1].push(el);
    return newArray;
  }, []);
}
```

If you also want to avoid the `push` and, for whatever reasons, statements at all, you can `concat`:

```
const sliceGroupingBy = (arr, fn) =>
  arr.reduce((newArray, el) =>
    fn(el)
      ? newArray.concat([[el]]);
      : newArray.slice(0, -1).concat(newArray.slice(-1).map(lastArray =>
          lastArray.concat([el])
        )
  , []);
```

("altering" the last element of the array could be done in a myriad of ways)

Comment: Similar to the approach I ended up taking after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Grossly inefficient but:

```
let predicate = x => x % 2 === 1;
let partition = (pred, arr) => {
  let res1 = arr.filter(pred);
  let res2 = arr.filter(x => !pred(x));
  return [res1, res2];
};

partition(predicate, [1,2,3,...]);
```

I'd never do it that way in JavaScript though (assume from the code that's the language in question). See my comments on your question.

### EDIT

Per the comment that I was wrong about what you're doing,

```
let xs = array.reduce((acc, x, i, arr) => {
  let lastIndex = acc.reduce((y, z) => { y + z.length }, 0);
  return predicate(x) || i === arr.length - 1 ?
    acc.concat([arr.slice(lastIndex, i)]) :
    acc;
}, []);
```

Uses no statements, only expressions, no mutation, only copying. I still wouldn't do this without using immutable.js or mori. Its rather expensive.

### EDIT 2

More efficient version of the last approach based on comment from Bergi:

```
let {result} = array.reduce((obj, x, i, arr) => {
  let {lastIndex, result} = obj;
  let passes = predicate(x) || i === arr.length - 1;
  return {
    lastIndex: passes ? i : lastIndex,
    result: passes ? result.concat([arr.slice(lastIndex, i)]) : result
  };
}, { lastIndex: 0, result: [] });
```

Comment: OP is not doing `partition`, he's splitting before every element that the predicate selects

Comment: I don't get your new solution. What is `lastIndex`, it seems to be a number at times and an array otherwise? Also, what is the `i === arr.length-1` check good for, and why don't you "modify" `acc` in case the predicate doesn't match?

Comment: @Bergi typo, should have been the length of the previous arrays. I made it a `reduce` so no ternary conditional. This uses the combined length of the previously added arrays to track the last break and then slices the parent array on that and the current index if the predicate is true or its the end of the parent array.

Comment: Ah, it begins to make sense now. Nice idea! You probably could make it more efficient by keeping the `lastIndex` in the accumulator (`.reduce(({lastIndex, arr}, x, i) => …, {lastIndex: 0, arr:[]}).arr`)

Comment: @Bergi yes indeed, although frankly if efficiency is any kind of worry one would never do this in the first place :)